# Dojo Date picker Vs Jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Can any one suggest which date picker is better in terms of usablity/weight/Customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) samples.
Honestly jQuery is more comfortable and flexible choose jQuery UI Datepicker.

> The jQuery UI Datepicker is a highly
>   configurable plugin that adds
>   datepicker functionality to your
>   pages. You can customize the date
>   format and language, restrict the
>   selectable date ranges and add in
>   buttons and other navigation options
>   easily.
>
> By default, the datepicker calendar
>   opens in a small overlay onFocus and
>   closes automatically onBlur or when a
>   date is selected. For an inline
>   calendar, simply attach the datepicker
>   to a div or span.
>
> You can use keyboard shortcuts to
>   drive the datepicker:
>
> ```
> page up/down - previous/next month
> ctrl+page up/down - previous/next year
> ctrl+home - current month or open when closed
> ctrl+left/right - previous/next day
> ctrl+up/down - previous/next week
> enter - accept the selected date
> ctrl+end - close and erase the date
> escape - close the datepicker without selection
> ```